# C++ - Создание типа конкретного размера

Tags: c++, typedef, sizeof

У меня есть необходимость хранить значение цвета в формате 0xAARRGGBB, то есть, нужен тип, занимающий 4 байта. Я использую `unsigned int`, но, насколько знаю, на 32-разрядном процессоре,  `uint`, в зависимости от компилятора, может весить 2 байта. Возникает вопрос, как бы объявить тип `ARGB`, чтобы он занимал 4 байта, через `typedef`? Можно ли как-нибудь, например, через условную компиляцию, сделать `typedef` от `unsigned`, если `sizeof(unsigned) == 4` и от `unsigned long` иначе? Я не хочу создавать класс, содержащий 4 `char`'а, мне нужно, чтобы он был числовым, в т.ч. чтобы работал вариант

```
ARGB color = 0xff000000;
```

На данный момент у меня просто `typedef unsigned int ARGB;`

P.S.
Qt использует такой же
`typedef unsigned int QRgb;`
Однако, как я понимаю, qmake использует компилятор, в котором `int` всегда весит 4 байта

Comment: Вы для всех времен и народов (экзотических компиляторов) свою программу ваяете? (обычно, начиная с 32-bit CPU  `int` (и `unsigned int`) имеет размер 4 байта).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрим в [сstdint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) и выбираем тип `uint32_t`...

Если очень хочется выкрутиться через `sizeof`, то можно поиграться в шаблонные игры типа

```
template<size_t N>
struct uint
{
    using type = 
        conditional_t<sizeof(unsigned char) == N, unsigned char,
        conditional_t<sizeof(unsigned short int) == N, unsigned short int,
        conditional_t<sizeof(unsigned int) == N, unsigned int,
        conditional_t<sizeof(unsigned long) == N, unsigned long,
        conditional_t<sizeof(unsigned long long) == N, unsigned long long,
        void>>>>>;
    static_assert(!is_same_v<type,void>,"Error - type not exist");
};

using  u4int = uint<4>::type;
```

Answer (score 3):

Стандартная библиотеки языков С и С++ не гарантируют наличия типов *конкретного* размера, т.е. наличия типов вроде `std::uint32_t` не гарантируется - это *опциональные* типы. Если вы хотите портабельности/платформеннонезависимости вашего кода на уровне языка, то либо используйте тип минимально достаточного размера, вроде `std::uint_least32_t`, либо конструируйте некий свой агрегатный тип самостоятельно. Если вам нужна бинарная междуплатформенная портабельность, то остается лишь последний вариант.

Comment: cstdint не является стандартной библиотекой? Или не каждый компилятор подразумевает наличие uint32_t?

Comment: @Rabter: Именно наличия `std::uint32_t` не гарантируется, как и наличия любых других типов *точной* ширины. Типы `...least...` и `...fast...` обязаны присутствовать в `<stdint.h>` (и в `<cstdint>`), а вот *точные* типы  - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы действительно не знаете для какой системы и каким компилятором будет транслироваться программа то стоит учесть, что есть системы как little-endian так и big-endian. Именно поэтому стоит использовать четыре байта. А если быть точнее то именно четыре uint8_t. Таким образом порядок байт и их разрядность будет соблюдена.
Для удобства можно создать класс, который будет приводить данную структуру к unsigned int путем побитового сдвига, что также будет гарантировать правильное расположение значений цвета во всех системах.

Comment: uint8_t занимает 1 байт

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я имел ввиду четыре uint8_t.

Comment: зачем? И при чем тут порядок байт? - пока нет обмена данными между машинами с разным порядком байт, то это не имеет никакого значения

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Например,если Вы хотите чтобы ваша программа правильно обрабатывала BMP файлы на разных системах тогда это  имеет значение. Хорошие программы обычно это учитывают.

Comment: вы понимаете, что если нет обмена данными, то никакой проблемы нет? И ваш аргумент про "хорошие" программы не имеет смысла, если программе не надо обрабатывать данные передаваемые между литл и биг эндиан машинами. И даже в этом случае не нужно ради этого городить говнокод, а просто написать что-то вроде транслятора, который приведет  полученные байты в нужный порядок.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Во первых речь идет об исходном коде, который будет транслироваться разными компиляторами и под разные системы. Во вторых существуют форматы данных которые имеют строгий порядок расположения. И если Вы считаете, что ваш код не должен учитывать особенности разных систем это ваше право, но о переносимости можете забыть. И если кто то захочет использовать такой код на другой платформе для него будет сюрпризом такой не говнокод.

Comment: а вы понимаете, что 1) вопрос был вообще не об этом - вы притянули это за уши, 2) сериализация и десериализация - отдельные этапы программы, и не стоит мешать их с обработкой данных (про это я говорил "говнокод" - печально, что это приходится пояснять, хотя я уже об этом писал).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Печально, что Вы никогда не сталкивались с обработкой изображений на разных платформах.

Comment: а кто вам сказал, что не сталкивался? Ванга нашептала? И с каких это пор для работы с изображениями используют 1 4битных инт на 4 значения, вместо 4 однобитных - не просветите? И сразу предупрежу эти комменты в виде: "ха, а кто вам сказал, что 4 канала, а не 2 по 2 байта" и тому подобное - в вопросе конкретно указан формат.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch В вопросе помимо формата еще и указан конкретный порядок, что в общем и привело к данному ответу. Вы уже выразили свое несогласие с моим ответом. Но,я все равно считаю его полезным.

Answer (score 1):

> Я не хочу создавать класс, содержащий 4 char'а, мне нужно, чтобы он
>   был числовым, в т.ч. чтобы работал вариант
>
> ARGB color = 0xff000000;

Если уж Вы работаете в С++, то как раз нужно создать класс, содержащий 4 char'а. А потом перегрузить присваивание константой для этого класса, чтобы работало ARGB color = 0xff000000;

Это и будет С++-way. :-)

Comment: Логично. Правда, работать будет медленнее

Comment: @Rabter Потом на операциях с отдельными цветами время съэкономится. Все равно при хранении цветов в одном целом типа int приходится накладывать маску и сдвигать чтобы выделить один цвет.